# What does being back to something mean?

Tags: idioms, dialogue, cinema

What does the phrase "Now it's back to all the brightness, and everything I hate" mean? (Riddicks s dialogue in The Chronicles of Riddicks movie) 
https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick

Is the whole dialogue a famous idiom or a part of it? If it contains such an idiom, please tell me. 
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no idiomatic expression here overall, except for the verb: to be back to something. That said, in regular speech, to describe a situation, a speaker will often say: Now, we're back to [some condition or state]. And the "to be back to" is followed by a condition or state can be said by a person or it can be attributed to a situation. Here, it's for a situation, "Now, it's [the situation] is back to A [condition].

Of course, to be back to something just means to have returned to a place, situation or condition. A paraphrase of the sentence would read: We have now returned to a situation of brightness. And brightness, well, that is a lot of light, or perhaps better said, not darkness....

Comment: Thank you for complete answer. So maybe this dialogue wants to say I hate brightness and some other things but situation is against me, turned back to brightness and other things. Am I right?

Comment: The situation of brightness and other things is something "I don't like". :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a famous idiom, just merely an observation by Riddick that he is *returning* to that place.

The word [**back**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/back) in this phrase is being used as an adverb.

> - 2 - So as to return to an earlier or normal position or condition.
> - 3 - In or into the past
> - 4 - In return